# I'm not sure why my Trigger is having problems

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I am a college student that has an assignment due and I am not sure how to resolve this issue I am having. I attempted to create a trigger so that AFTER the patients are inserted/deleted into/from the PATIENT table, values (in the IF statements) are inserted into a new table, patient_log.

Attempts:
1. My INSERT statement works(I tested it separately from trigger and if statement). 
2. I also attempted "REFERENCES OLD AS OLD NEW AS NEW"
3. I've attempted to add the ":" in front of "NEW" and "OLD" but SQL pops up an error message of incorrect referencing.

**** Please keep the coding as simple as possible. In other words, code should be as if you are learning the basics of Procedures and Triggers(I hope that makes sense).

```
set pagesize 100
set linesize 130
set echo on

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER after_pat AFTER INSERT OR DELETE ON patient 
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
pat_name1 VARCHAR(41);

BEGIN
SELECT pat_name INTO pat_name1 FROM patient
    WHERE patient_ID = :NEW.patient_ID OR patient_ID = :OLD.patient_ID;

IF inserting THEN
    INSERT INTO patient_log
 VALUES('New patient '||NEW.pat_name1||' inserted at ', TO_CHAR(sysdate,'Month DD, YYYY HH:MI PM'));
END IF;

IF deleting THEN 
    INSERT INTO patient_log
        VALUES('Patient '||OLD.pat_name1||' released at ',TO_CHAR(sysdate,'Month DD, YYYY HH:MI PM')); 
END IF;

END after_pat;
/

__________________________________________________________________
>ERROR CODES I get: 
>It's for the IF statements i.e. "IF inserting then" & "IF deleting then"
>
>LINE/COL ERROR
>-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
>9/2      PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored<BR>
>10/29    PL/SQL: ORA-00984: column not allowed here
>14/2     PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored<BR>
>15/26    PL/SQL: ORA-00984: column not allowed here
SQL> 
______________________________________________________
> SQL> desc patient_log;
 Name  Type
 **MESSAGE**                                                                          VARCHAR2(50)
 **TIME1**                                                               VARCHAR2(30)
```

Comment: mysql, sql-server and oracle are three different providers. Please [edit] the question to tag the one you are using, and remove the other two tags.

Comment: My apologies. I am currently using Oracle SQL*PLUS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, move your SELECT inside the `if inserting/deleting`, and adapt it accordingly : **either** you search for a NEW record, **or** for an OLD record, not both at the same time.

Then just use your variable `pat_name1` inside your INSERT INTO logs. The error occurs because instead of the variable, you use there `NEW.pat_name1`  and `OLD.pat_name1` which are invalid

Something like this :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER after_pat AFTER INSERT OR DELETE ON patient 
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
pat_name1 VARCHAR(41);

BEGIN

IF INSERTING THEN

    SELECT pat_name INTO pat_name1 FROM patient WHERE patient_ID = :NEW.patient_ID;

    INSERT INTO patient_log  VALUES('New patient ' || pat_name1 || ' inserted at ', TO_CHAR(sysdate,'Month DD, YYYY HH:MI PM'));

END IF;

IF DELETING THEN 

    SELECT pat_name INTO pat_name1 FROM patient WHERE patient_ID = :OLD.patient_ID;

    INSERT INTO patient_log VALUES('Patient ' || pat_name1 || ' released at ',TO_CHAR(sysdate,'Month DD, YYYY HH:MI PM')); 
END IF;

END after_pat;
/
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Thomas G !  Trigger has been created.
Now, all I need to do is to resolve:
**ORA-04091: table SYSTEM.PATIENT is mutating, trigger/function may not see it**
From when I test the data with insert statements.